# ASP.NET - install React and typescript

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, npm

So have created an ASP.NET 4.5.2 project and now need to install react and typescript. I installed node.js so wondering if its best to install via that. Also because I will be using TypeScript I will need the .d.ts files is there an easy way to install these in the project locally? Cause I assume everything else will be installed globally by npm as I might use them in other projects?

One other thing I am confused by all the different types of react packages available on npm, do i need a few or just one of them? I have worked on many projects involving this kind of tech stack but they are established and have never created one from scratch like i am doing now. So some really informative links or tips here would be immensely helpful! :)

Comment: So far have tried this https://medium.com/@lucavgobbi/using-react-with-typescript-on-visual-studio-39cd0a77fdd2 and using some help from the comments got it kind of working but had issues with it not updating when i refresh after updating a .tsx component as a test. Also had some issues a few builds in with something about roslyn not being able to be located. Got that one sorted though.

Comment: No progress still unfortunately, I am very confused on how to install and configure everything. Can't find one good tutorial and have been looking for days....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using Visual Studio 2017 I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@lucavgobbi/using-react-with-typescript-on-visual-studio-39cd0a77fdd2) and managed to get it working. The only issue left now is that i need to call webpack cmd on the project root when i make changes before refreshing the site. I am fine with this and will look into further into automating it as it kind of is a different and unrelated question.

One thing I will include is to always install npm packages globally (most of the time anyway) and just link them in using npm link. Was quite useful considering I went through the process a few times creating the project from scratch over and over again until I understood it all.